# CURL return data handling

Tags: php, curl, google-plus

I've written a PHP function to get plus ones count for a URL

```
function makeApiCall($destinationUrl, $stringOfParams){
  $curl = curl_init();
  echo $destinationUrl.$stringOfParams."<br>";
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $destinationUrl.$stringOfParams);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  echo $result;
 }
```

While inputting `https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton` as destination URL and inputting the correct string of params, the result I'm receiving in `$result` is HTML.
The problem is that I would like using PHP to get the count and not using JavaScript.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match), you can achieve it.

Assuming you are calling a url like that :

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?bsv=pr&url=http://www.google.com
```

You are looking for:

```
<div id="aggregateCount" class="t1">118k</div>
```

or

```
<div id="aggregateCount" class="t1">12</div>
```

So you can perform:

```
preg_match('/\<div id=\"aggregateCount\" class=\"t1\"\>\>?([0-9]*k?)\<\/div\>/i', $result, $matches);
```

And `$matches` will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <div id="aggregateCount" class="t1">118k</div>
    [1] => 118k
)
```

**edit:**

After running the example, it seems that Google return a different number when using curl, for example, on `http://www.google.com`, it returns:

```
<div id="aggregateCount" class="t1">>9999</div>
```

So I've updated the regex to handle the `>`.

Comment: That's sounds like a decent solution but it didn't work for me. I'm getting array 0 if I var_dump $matches. The url example I'm using is "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?count=true&url=http://www.google.com"